# simply connectedness in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $D_1$ and $D_2$ are simply connected domains in the complex plane whose intersection is is non-empty and connected. Prove that $D_1\cap D_2$ and $D_1\cup D_2$ are simply connected

The definition that I have for Simply connected domains is as follows

**Defn:** A region $\Omega$ is called simply connected if for all $f$ holomorphic in $\Omega$, there exists a function $F$ holomorphic in $\Omega$ such that $F'=f$.

I have the proof for $D_1 \cup D_2$, but I can't show, using this definition that the intersection is also simply connected.

It is true that if $f$ is holomorphic in the intersection, then there is a function $\tilde{f}$ holomorphic on $D_1$ or $D_2$ such that $\tilde{f}|_{D_1\cap D_2}=f$??

Comment: As for your last paragraph the answer is no: given any open set in the complex plane, there exists a holomorphic function there that can't be extended to any open set properly containing the original.